# Forum Submit 60 seconds time limit

Tags: php, forms

How would I force users to wait 60 seconds before submitting another email?

I can use `session` and `time()`. Any code examples is welcome.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Cookies can be edited with special add-ons so I prefer you to use **sessions** and **microtime**. Something like that:

```
$delay = 60000000; // Set delay [60 seconds]

// .......

if(microtime() >= $_SESSION['lastsent'] + $delay)
{
   send();
   $_SESSION['lastsent'] = microtime();
}
else
{
   echo 'Please wait 60 seconds';
}
```

Code can be bad cause it have been written here.

Comment: yes something like this :-) Can you give more complete example of it do ? Like with echo for example. Please wait 60 seconds to send again. Thanks.

Comment: Perfect, thank you Robik. Will try it and let you know if it worked for me =)

Comment: @EMC it is simple else sttement.... But if you can't... [Answer modified]

Comment: I can't seem to implement this with codeigniter using http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html  I'm using this code inside contact.php controller in function send() {}  But after I click submit it just shows me message to wait 60 seconds and I don't get any eamils. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

If you put onclick="disable(event)" on your form's send button, then supply this script fragment:

```
function disable(event) = {
  event.currentTarget.setAttribute("style", "display:none");
  window.setTimeout(function() {
     event.currentTarget.setAttribute("style", "display:inline");
  }, 1000 * 60);
}
```

Beware however this only implements the check on the client (browser) side. It's easily hacked out by bad users. You'll need to implement a similar check on the server side.

Comment: This is very nice and useful, but its javascript. Thanks, but I need php :)

Comment: Your question is tagged 'javascript'

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. I thought I sait PHP :( In fact I did, it was edited by stuff what the?

Comment: How strange! Will leave this here just in case it's useful for anyone.

Answer (score 0):

Use session state (not sure how that's done in PHP but this isn't a PHP issue) or a cookie to store the last submission time. It's a simple compare and act after that.

Comment: I'm sorry but that does not help LOL

Comment: @EMC: How does that not help and what's amusing about that? I guess from that you are looking for a complete piece of code rather than just an explanation of how to do it. This isn't rocket science.

Comment: exactly :-) I am looking for code examples.

Comment: @EMC: So I see, well, learning is over-rated.